# jQuery UI autocomplete init but doesn't show, how to track the error?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm applying autocomplete on an input:

```
$('#email_user').html('<input type="text" id="email_input" value="'+user_email+'">');
$('#email_input').autocomplete({source: emails_directory});
```

It worked, but after some development on other parts of the page it stopped displaying. (I can't display code here, it is a 10k lines project and more or less anything could be conflicting)

I'm trying to track the error so I did the following :

- I checked the console, no error message.
- I inspected the input and noticed that it got `autocomplete="off"` which is a clue that the autocomplete instantiate more or less properly.
- I have styled my css with a high z-index thinking it could be hidden by something, no change

Something is wrong but I don't know what and I have no clue about how to track anything else....

Answer (score 0):

I see only two possible reasons for your issue :

1) a css display property problem.
2) a problem with your data source.

```js
var emails_directory=  ["dir1","dir2","dir3","dir4"]
$('#email_user').html('<input type="text" id="email_input" value="email@email.fr">');
$('#email_input').autocomplete({source: emails_directory});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id='email_user'>
</div>
```

Comment: I echo my datasource in the console and it is fine. The includes are alright too.
It might be the css, but how can I see it, I don't find the ui-menu class in my inspector. Is there a way in chrome to track a specific class?

Comment: If the `ul` with classes `ui-autocomplete  ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ` is created, try to define the display `property` of this div to  `block `

Comment: where is the ul supposed to be created, right after my input ? any possibility to search for it in some way via the inspector ?

Comment: You can try to find this `$(".ui-autocomplete")` by adding a watch in chrome inspector (source tab)

Comment: ok thanks, I tried this and also with ui-menu and the length parameter in the watch remains at 0

Comment: You should paste more code on SO or host your webpage to get more help :)

Comment: yes, but unfortunately not possible :)
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail, it's a bit hard to determine why it's not showing up.

I offer another way to draw it up:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/z8pwwxr5/

```
var user_email = 'user@example.com';
var emails_directory = ["dir1","dir2","dir3","dir4"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $newInput = $('<input>', {
    type: "text",
    id: "email_input",
    placeholder: user_email
  }).appendTo($("#email_user")).autocomplete({
    source: emails_directory
  });
});
```

If you want the AutoComplete to appear on focus, that can be done too.Again, without a more complete question, it's hard to address the root cause.